# CMS for ecommerce website in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, e-commerce, web

Are there any CMS available in rails which we can extends as per need for ecommerce website ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check out [Spree](http://spreecommerce.com/) and its [source code](https://github.com/railsdog/spree).

Answer (score 1):

Two Rails CMS' that I've come across several times are [RefineryCMS](http://refinerycms.com/) and [RadiantCMS](http://radiantcms.org/). I think you would definitely want to be working in the context of Rails 3, since it's a better foundation for working with modularity in the form of engines.